# How to monitor file changes in remote centos host without monitoring or without third party tools

Tags: python, file, monitoring, centos7

How to monitor file changes in remote centos host.
without monitoring tools and without third party tools.

Comment: Is that like, how to fight without fighting.

Comment: Which monitoring tool is best to check file changes in remote server

Comment: Given that you have accepted an answer which clearly does not answer your question, I suggest that you put your new question to @Cheney but as your new question asks for an opinion, it would break the rules of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean only using python, then try this [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog). As for remote use `socket`,`API`,`RPC`...